# Countdown timer for Lua script

Tags: lua, coronasdk, countdown

I am completely new to the Lua programming language, I've only been working with it a few days in total. Although, I do have some experience in Python, C# and Ada.

I am currently trying to make a racing game, one of the aspects of the game I'm trying to include is a countdown timer that ends the game after 90 seconds, then returning to a high score screen, regardless of whether or not the player has eliminated all of their lives already. I haven't a clue what functions to include nor where the place the text in the main script. Some advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When the game starts do:

```
local startTime = os.time()
local endTime = startTime+90
```

Then regularely do:

```
if os.time() >= endTime then
    -- exit game
    -- return to high score screen
end
```

until the game ends. Probably this would be in a callback function that gets called regularely. Depending on how your framework works, a loop might also work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [timer.performWithDelay](http://timer.performWithDelay()) to call a specified function after a delay.

**Example**

```
local function countdown( event )
    print( "listener called" )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, countdown, 90 )
```